# Google Reward Video ads works with test ad unit id , but not with live adunit id

Tags: android, admob, admob-rewardedvideoad

I have a strange problem implementing Google Reward Video. In test mode (with google ad-id) works perfect first time, but not loading video in the second time. In production (with my ids) not loading video at all. Here is my code:

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import eu.healthydev.quizhero.Common.Common;
import eu.healthydev.quizhero.Model.Question;
import eu.healthydev.quizhero.Model.QuestionScore;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardItem;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardedVideoAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardedVideoAdListener;

public class DoneActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RewardedVideoAdListener{

    Button btnTryAgain, exit_game;
    TextView txtResultScore, getTxtResultQuestion;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference question_score;

    //VideoAd Award
    private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-5883754622051955/6179215953";
    private static final String APP_ID = "ca-app-pub-5883754622051955~8837168889";


    private int coinCount;
    private TextView coinCountText;

    private RewardedVideoAd rewardedVideoAd;

    private Button showVideoButton;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_done);

        // Initialize the Mobile Ads SDK.
        MobileAds.initialize(this, APP_ID);

        rewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
        rewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);
        loadRewardedVideoAd();





        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        question_score = database.getReference("Question_Score");

        txtResultScore = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTotalScore);
        getTxtResultQuestion =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTotalQuestion);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.doneProgressBar);


        // Create the "retry" button, which tries to show an interstitial between game plays.
        btnTryAgain = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnTryAgain);
        exit_game = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exit_game);

        btnTryAgain.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        btnTryAgain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(DoneActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        // Create the "show" button, which shows a rewarded video if one is loaded.
        showVideoButton = findViewById(R.id.show_video_button);
        showVideoButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        showVideoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showRewardedVideo();
            }
        });

        exit_game.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        exit_game.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });






        // Display current coin count to user.
        coinCountText = findViewById(R.id.coin_count_text);
        coinCount = 0;
        coinCountText.setText("Coins: " + coinCount);






        //Get data from bundle and set view
        Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extra != null)
        {
            int score = extra.getInt("SCORE");
            int totalQuestion = extra.getInt("TOTAL");
            int correctAnswer = extra.getInt("CORRECT");

            txtResultScore.setText(String.format("SCORE : %d", score));
            getTxtResultQuestion.setText(String.format("PASSED : %d /%d", correctAnswer,totalQuestion));

            progressBar.setMax(totalQuestion);
            progressBar.setProgress(correctAnswer);

            //Upload points to Database
            question_score.child(String.format("%s_%s", Common.currentUser.getUserName(),
                    Common.categoryID))
                    .setValue(new QuestionScore(String.format("%s_%s", Common.currentUser.getUserName(),
                            Common.categoryID),
                            Common.currentUser.getUserName(),
                            String.valueOf(score),
                            Common.categoryID,
                            Common.categoryName));

        }
    }




    private void loadRewardedVideoAd() {
        if (!rewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
            rewardedVideoAd.loadAd(AD_UNIT_ID, new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }
    }

    private void addCoins(int coins) {
        coinCount += coins;
        coinCountText.setText("Coins: " + coinCount);
    }





    private void showRewardedVideo() {
        showVideoButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        exit_game.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        if (rewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
            rewardedVideoAd.show();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {

        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdClosed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Preload the next video ad.
        loadRewardedVideoAd();
        btnTryAgain.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        showVideoButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        exit_game.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Ad Video Failed to Load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        showVideoButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        exit_game.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLoaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewarded(RewardItem reward) {
        Toast.makeText(this,
                String.format(" You ve got one free try!", reward.getType(),
                        reward.getAmount()),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        btnTryAgain.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        showVideoButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        exit_game.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        addCoins(1);
        Intent intent = new Intent(DoneActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        finishAffinity();
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

    }

}
```

I double checked my ids and are correct. Probably my code too as it works ane time exactly as it has to do. I will appriciate any help or idea.

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

From: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-video

```
@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
    // Load the next rewarded video ad.
    loadRewardedVideoAd();
}
```

We need to re-load once the first one is closed.
My app is working fine due to same. Hope that helps.